# Regex returns text of every line with match, when text is inside variable

Tags: python, regex, variables, grep

How can one formulate a regex in Python to return the line where the pattern is found, in a `grep`-like manner? Say I have the following text (the output of a shell command called with `subprocess`), assigned to a variable called output:

```
output = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.\nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard\nIt has survived not only five centuries\nIt was popularised in the 1960s with the release of"
```

(sorry about the length, but it's closer to a real example. So the challenge now is to split the string according to `\n` and then search every line independently. So, we can start with

```
output_lines = re.split(r'\n', output)
```

and get a list, where each element is a line. We now have:

```
 >>> print output_lines
['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.',
 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard',
 'It has survived not only five centuries',
 'It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of']
```

How would you suggest I search through `output_lines` for the lines that contain my requested pattern, say "Lorem"?

I tried the obvious:

```
for line in output_lines:
    if re.search(r"Lorem",line):
        print line
```

And it works. But, does anyone know of a more compact (and possibly elegant) way to get this done?

Comment: `next(line for line in output.split('\n') if 'Lorem' in line)`

Comment: @Blender avoid answering in comments!!!!

Comment: I tried that and Python threw an error. What module is `next` from?

Comment: @Seabiscuit its built-in actually

Comment: @Seabiscuit: What error?

Comment: Regex is overkill if you're just checking if a string is contained in another.

Comment: @KDawG I'm on Python 2.4.3. Maybe it hasn't been packaged for that version?

Comment: @Blender `>>> next(line for line in output.split('\n') if 'Lorem' in line)`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?`
`NameError: name 'next' is not defined`

Comment: @Seabiscuit: Well, that's why. Python 2.4.3 was released almost 8 years ago. Most assume you're going to be using Python 2.7 or Python 3.3.

Comment: @Volatility Would you care to post your solution as an answer? Clearly, I haven't thought of attacking the problem from the perspective you're mentioning without seeking recourse to Regex.

Comment: @Seabiscuit K DawG has put it in his answer - it's easiest to just use `'Lorem' in i`

Comment: @Volatility Nicely, I see the answer below. That's the response I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple one liner would be:

```
output_lines = [i for i in re.split(r'\n', output) if "Lorem" in i]
print output_lines
```

Output:

```
['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.', "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard"]
```

*Just for the fact: Regex is way too overkill However if you need regex:*

```
output_lines = [i for i in re.split(r'\n', output) if re.search("Lorem",i)]
```

Comment: For the regex solution: `output_lines = re.findall(r'.*Lorem.*', output)` would work as well (but still overkill)

Comment: @Volatility exactly however the OP was just using a example, god knows what he's really got ;)

Comment: Nice. My rookie strut is starting to show. Not least because I haven't detached from the bosom of my seriously outdated school server and it's 2.4.3 version of Python. Thanks K Dawg!

Comment: @Volatility Wouldn't your regex simply return the entire output if the word Lorem is found within it?

Comment: @Seabiscuit [`.` doesn't match newlines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) unless the `DOTALL` flag is specified.